# jscrollPane not working at all

Tags: jquery, jscrollpane

I know I use a **bad** title but I can't describe it different.

The code is here : http://jsfiddle.net/FFjgc/3/

**Header** :

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://jscrollpane.kelvinluck.com/style/jquery.jscrollpane.css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://jscrollpane.kelvinluck.com/script/jquery.jscrollpane.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://jscrollpane.kelvinluck.com/script/jquery.mousewheel.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://jscrollpane.kelvinluck.com/script/mwheelIntent.js"></script>


<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.scroll').jScrollPane();
});
</script>
```

And the **css**

```
.scroll {
width: 100%;
height: 200px;
overflow: auto;
}
```

It's so simple, I use all the libraries and I'm sure there is no error in the code since I'm looking at it the last 2 hours.

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no problem with the jQuery version. You should wrap your content with `p` tag to run Jscrollpane. In this way your content will look more [semantic](http://reference.sitepoint.com/html/p).

[Example Here](http://jsfiddle.net/agriboz/FFjgc/5/)

Answer (score 2):

I ran this issue and finally jScrollPane is working with all its features using jQuery 1.9.1.

The solution was very straightforward: initialize the plugin on window.load.

```
$(window).load(function) {
  $(".your-selector").jScrollPane();
}
```

I hope this help someone

Answer (score 0):

The problem is de Jquery version.

Test with http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js